# CAGradientLayer: other UIObjects not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

When I use the CAGradientLayer on iOS to set up gradient for my viewcontroller, objects that I had previously placed using my interface builder are not showing up. When I take the gradientLayer function away, these objects show up. Also, when I add these objects programatically as a subview they show up in the iOS simulator. What's going on? Here is my gradientLayer code:

```
func setUpGradient(){
    let topColor=UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 149/255, blue: 56/255,alpha: 1)
let bottomColor=UIColor(red: 216/255, green: 57/255, blue: 177/255, 
alpha: 1)
    let gradientColors: [CGColor]=[topColor.cgColor,bottomColor.cgColor]
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors=gradientColors
    gradientLayer.startPoint=CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint=CGPoint(x: 0, y:1)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple which is the gradient layer covers all the elements when you add them in IB by this line

```
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

so you may insert it below them like this

```
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer,at:0)
```

Comment: sorry- new to swift... thanks for the explanation but what do you mean "insert it below them." Is there any way to use the interface editor to add in the other components, rather than programatically after I create the gradient?

Comment: You can also subclass UIView implement the gradient addition and assign that class to the view in IB

Comment: Every UI element is a layer so inserting means placing the gradient the back-most